# how to get callback from inline keyboard telegram

Tags: python, bots, telegram

I know how to send inline keybard button message but i want to know how to recive callbackdata
when user press on it

```
 keyboard = [
                [InlineKeyboardButton("Click button 1", callback_data='callback_1')],
                [InlineKeyboardButton("Click button 1", callback_data='callback_2')]
            ]
    reply_markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(keyboard)
    message_reply_text = 'Click one of these buttons'
    user_message.message.reply_text(message_reply_text, reply_markup=reply_markup)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `CallbackQueryHandler` to assign function which will be executed when you click button.

```
dp.add_handler(CallbackQueryHandler(keyboard_callback))
```

and you can get it as

```
update.callback_query.data
```

---

```
from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler, CallbackQueryHandler
from telegram import InlineKeyboardButton, InlineKeyboardMarkup
import os

TOKEN = os.getenv('TELEGRAM_TOKEN')

def start(update, context):
    keyboard = [
                [InlineKeyboardButton("Click button 1", callback_data='callback_1')],
                [InlineKeyboardButton("Click button 1", callback_data='callback_2')]
               ]
    reply_markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(keyboard)
    message_reply_text = 'Click one of these buttons'
    update.message.reply_text(message_reply_text, reply_markup=reply_markup)

def keyboard_callback(update, context):
    query = update.callback_query
    #print('query:', query)
    
    print('query.data:', query.data)
    query.answer(f'selected: {query.data}')

if __name__=='__main__':
    update = Updater(TOKEN, use_context=True)
    dp = update.dispatcher

    dp.add_handler(CommandHandler("start", start))
   
    dp.add_handler(CallbackQueryHandler(keyboard_callback))
   
    print('Starting ...')
    update.start_polling()
    update.idle()
```